# Execute sudo command non-interactively

Tags: bash, command, non-interactive

I would like to execute the following command without interaction:

```
sudo grep -e "test" /etc/sudoers
```

I have tried the following method:

```
tester@compute:~$ echo 'clouduser' | sudo -S grep -e "test" /etc/sudoers
[sudo] password for tester: test ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

The problem is that I am getting the `[sudo] password for tester:`  in front of the response.
How I can cut that part from the front of the answer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will answer to my question - maybe someone else will need it:

```
(echo 'clouduser' | sudo -Si >/dev/null 2>&1); sudo grep -e test /etc/sudoers
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your `/etc/sudoers` file in order to turn on password-less sudo. In this case, I use `john` as the login account. Change to your own account id.

```
john ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Alternatively, and perhaps better is to put that line into a file called `/etc/sudoers.d/john`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I needed to do that operation without any manual intervention before. I have found the answer meanwhile and posted the answer how to do it.